# picasso cannot save to sd card from same url

Tags: java, android, picasso

I want to save image from url to storage through picasso, but i have a problem with my code.

i've a variable to save image.

```
String urlImage = "http://mylink/buzz/test2.jpg";
```

this one is worked
but when i use

```
fileUrl = fileName +"." + fileType;
String urlImage = "http://mylink/buzz/" + fileUrl;
```

not worked

content of fileUrl is test2.jpg

here is my code to save image

```
private Target picassoImageTarget(Context context, final String imageDir, final String imageName) {
    Log.d("picassoImageTarget", " picassoImageTarget");
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
    final File directory = cw.getDir(imageDir, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_imageDir
    return new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final File myImageFile = new File(directory, imageName); // Create image file
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(myImageFile);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            fos.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i("image", "image saved to >>>" + myImageFile.getAbsolutePath());

                }
            }).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            if (placeHolderDrawable != null) {}
        }
    };
}
```

and its code for call picasso.

```
Picasso.with(DrawerActivity.this).load(url).into(picassoImageTarget(getApplicationContext(), "imageDir", fileUrl));
```

Comment: What is the problem? is it any kind of exception? please specify.

Comment: have you requested write external storage permission?

Comment: @JeelVankhede when I use String urlImage my image saved to sdcard but when I use String urlImage = "http://mylink/buzz/" + fileUrl cannot saved to sdcard

fileurl is = test2.jpg

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes I have requested    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Have you requested it in runtime, or only in manifest?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko manifest..
when I use String urlImage = "http://mylink/buzz/test2.jpg"; my image saved to sdcard but when I use String urlImage = "mylink/buzz/"; + fileUrl cannot saved to sdcard 

the fileurl is = test2.jpg